Where do we learn out that Nimrod tried to make himself into a deity?
I've always vaguely remembered the conventional story of Nimrod declaring himself a god and Avraham challenging him to change the course of the sun, etc. But after doing some active digging, it seems the only source for Nimrod initiating his own apotheosis seems to be Midrash HaGadol (on Gen. 11:28). However, the Midrash HaGadol seems to claim that this idea originated with Chazal themselves ("אמרו חכמים וכו׳"). Is there any source other than MG that has Nimrod deifying himself?
Edit: clarified meaning of "earlier"
Edit 2: Lookings for any source now.

Not listed as one of the people who deified themselves in Shemot Rabba 8:2. Although one of them (Nevuchadnetzar) is called רשע בן רשע בן בנו של נמרוד הרשע שהמריד כל העולם כולו עליו במלכותו (Chagiga 13a)

Are there alternative versions of that list? Or just the one in Shmos Rabbah?

Nimrod asked Avraham to bow to water and stars, etc. Midrash Rabba 38:13. If he deified himself, he would ask to bow to himsef.

Could be from a now lost source.

Maybe it was a play on the words Beis Nimrod (Tower of Bavel) as in Avoda Zara 53b: Rabbi Yirmeya bar Abba says that Rav says: The temple of Nimrod, i.e., the remnants of the tower of Babel (see Genesis 11:1–9), is considered a place of idol worship whose worshippers abandoned it in peacetime, and it is therefore permitted.  (Although intended for worshiping stars).

In Bereshis Zuta 11:27 Nimrod calls himself Master of the whole world and requests that Abraham bow to him. The same story is In Eliyahu Zuta 25. But these are geonic and post geonic

woah! will check out

hey, it seems like Tanna DeVei Eliyahu Zuta only goes up to 15, not 25. :/

@Engidu I guess you probably looked at what Sefaria has. The rest of the book is in the appendices there (פרקי דרך ארץ and פרקי ר' אליעזר). You can also see here: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%AA%D7%A0%D7%90_%D7%93%D7%91%D7%99_%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95.
